# laoding csv with some malfromed data

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Im trying to read the csv in azure databricks and it gives me the following error.

```
df2 = (spark.read.format('csv')
           .option("delimiter", ",")
           .option("quote", '"')
           #.option("quoteAll", '"')
           .option("escape", '"')
           .option("header", "false")
           .option("path", '/mnt/d365/'+absolute+'/'+table_name+"/*.csv")
           .option("mode", "failfast")
#            .option("mode", "dropmalformed")
#            .option("mode", "permissive")
           .option("lineSep", "\r\n")
           .option("multiLine", "true")
#            .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")
           .schema(schema)
           .load()
      )

display(df2)
```

> "Caused by: MalformedCSVException: Malformed CSV record".

I have found some ways to bypass this problem but I dont want to use `.option("mode", "dropmalformed")` or `.option("mode", "permissive")`.

How am i suppose to discover which characters are the problem, identify where they are coming from, and fix them at the source

Comment: Did you check Spark logs, maybe it actually logged wrong record?

Comment: sorry, Im pretty new to this. do you mean if I tried to take a look at "corrupt records"?  https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/read-csv-corrupt-record.html